# Using multiprocessing to preprocess images

Tags: python

I am trying to get my feet wet using multiprocessing in python. As such, I am trying to operate an image preprocessing pipeline using multiprocessing. I have all my images in a directory called `image_files` and I have a list of all the filenames that are inside this directory. I split the list into two chunks `a` and `b` and pass each to its own `multiprocessing.Process` where a method called `preprocess_image` is doing the preprocessing on each image.

Following a tutorial on how to calculate square roots using multiprocessing I came up with a working code (see below).

This code works, however, speed matters and I am not sure whether it is appropriate to define two methods doing basically the same or if it would be faster to use only a single method and simply pass `a` and `b` to the same target in `multiprocessing.Process(target=work...` .

Hence my question is whether this is the right way to use multiprocessing or if I could speed it up somehow?

```
def work1(array):
    for i in tqdm(array):
        image_path = "C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/image_files/"+i

        image = preprocess_image(image_path)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/destination/"+i, image)

def work2(array):
    for i in tqdm(array):
        image_path = "C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/image_files/"+i

        image = preprocess_image(image_path)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/destination/"+i, image)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=work1, args=(a,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=work2, args=(b,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your process output seem to be independent, you should use `MultiProcessing.Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

l = # list of all your image files

f = # function to modify each of these, taking element of l as input.

p = Pool(10) # however many process you want to spawn

p.map(f, l)
```

That's it, you don't need to define the same function twice or manually split the list. It'll be automatically assigned and managed for you.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Is the number of processes I can spawn limited by the number of cores I have available? Also I wonder how to stop the entire process while running - using cmd + c doesn't do the trick it seems...

Comment: No, it is not limited, however in this case, more processes than CPU cores are probably not going to help performance, as they'll just wait in a queue. If you have IO intensive application then it make sense to have more process than number of cores. As to stopping it, the `Pool` generate `daemons` which will eventually be killed, but you might have to wait for the daemon to come back finished with current task - hence not immediate.